# In python, replace triple-nested if-else with more elegant way to clean up dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = [[1, 2.4, 3, np.nan], [4, 5.3, 6, np.nan], [np.nan, 8, 3, np.nan]]  # Example data
output_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['total', 'count1', 'count2', 'count3'])
output_data

    total   count1  count2  count3
0   1.0     2.4     3       NaN
1   4.0     5.3     6       NaN
2   NaN     8.0     3       NaN



# grab all columns to format
all_cols = ['total', 'count1', 'count2', 'count3', 'count4']
float_cols = ['total'] # dont want to convert these to integer

# add empty cols if they do not exist, and format columns correctly
for col in all_cols:
    # add empty col if it didnt exist
    if not (col in output_data.columns):
        output_data[col] = ''
    # else convert to integer-string with NA --> ''
    else:
        is_row_all_nulls = sum(output_data[col].isnull()) == output_data.shape[0]
        if is_row_all_nulls:
            output_data[col] = output_data[col].fillna(value = '')
        else:
            if (col in float_cols):
                output_data[col] = output_data[col].fillna('').astype(str)
            else:
                output_data[col] = output_data[col].fillna('').astype(str).str.split('.').str[0]
```

[image]

This code gives us exactly the output that we want. Columns with all NaN values get converted to empty strings. Not shown, but missing columns would be created and filled with empty strings. All columns are converted to strings, and NAN values are replaced with empty strings. The `total` column displays as a float within a string, whereas the other columns display as an integer within the string by chopping off everything after the decimal place via `str.split('.').str[0]`.

However, this triple-nested `if else` solution feels very messy. We would prefer to remove the nested `if else` with a cleaner, less-nested, more sophisticated solution. How could we achieve this?

**Edit:** updated with `count4` added to `all_cols`

Comment: you could use `continue` in the `if`-block. see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

Comment: Are you familiar with `elif`? Anyway, there are many different approaches to this problem, owing to the very specific circumstances of the problem. It does not make a good question for others to learn from, because it doesn't exemplify a pattern that can easily be asked about.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - yes but elif isn't going to do a ton to cleanup the code above.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It avoids all the nesting.

Comment: It does cleanup the code a bit, it does remove the nesting, but it maintains all of the same logic within the same number of conditions. In general, we are looking for a cleaner, more "python" solution than a "long" if-else chain.

Comment: This question is relatively focused, and has a working, reproducible code example. Why vote to close for being unfocused? This is a decent question with a useful answer posted already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
types = {c: int for c in all_cols}
for c in float_cols:
    types[c] = float
# or
# types = {'total': float, 'count1': int, 'count2': int, 'count3': int}

output_data = output_data.fillna(0).astype(types).mask(output_data.isna(), '')
```

Output:

```
  total  count1  count2 count3
0   1.0       2       3       
1   4.0       5       6       
2             8       3
```

Comment: This is great, better than my original code. Mask is a better way to handle `replace` type operations?

Comment: this doesn't handle missing columns, breaks if we add `count4` to `all_cols`, but that seems easy enough to add back in.

Comment: @Canovice yes, it depends exactly on how you want to handle it, don't hesitate to update your question if you need help ;)

Comment: has been updated. 
`for col in all_cols: if not (col in output_data.columns): output_data[col] = ''`

this would add the missing columns in, but I wonder if there is a more elegant one-liner that avoids the for loop and if statement

Comment: it seems like `output_data.reindex(columns=all_cols, fill_value='')` accomplishes this?